# How do websites display text from right to left for alphabets that read right to left?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Do all websites, regardless of alphabet display text from left to right?, if not how do you go about saving(**form)**, storing (**MySQL**) and then displaying(**HTML**) text that reads from right to left?

Comment: i don't know, Arabic seems they go from right to left

Answer (score 2):

For the CSS part you could use the following code:

```
direction: rtl;
```

You could also combine it with mirroring:

```
direction: rtl; unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
```

Also have a look at the following W3C article: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir#blockelements

And this one:
http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/styling_right-to-left_text_with_css_on_a_multi-lingual_site/

Comment: Thanks intCoffee. Generally do websites do this?.. as google seems to display all text regardless of alphabet from left to right? (and they're google)

Comment: Also I have just looked at this on w3 example, and it doesn't seem to work: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_direction

Comment: If you want to mirror it, you could add the following code:    direction: rtl; unicode-bidi:bidi-override;

Comment: Thanks intCoffee, that seems to work, however isn't that how it should work? as just direction: rtl;